# Calculating the tangent of a line with an arbitrary slope

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have a pygame grid with two points, x1 y2 and x2 y2.
I would like to calculate the points x3 y3 which correspond to a point on a tangent orthogonal to x1 y1 and x2 y2 and starts from x2 y2.

So far, I have thought about calculating the slope between x1 y1 and x2 y2 and then using the formula

```
tangent_slope = 1/((x1-x2)/(y1-y2))
```

to receive the slope of the tangent. However, this approach fails when y1 and y2 are the same value, as the slope would then approach infinity. I would like to avoid making the explicit distinction for this case and prefer a solution that includes every case and simply returns a dot that would be on the tangent orthogonal to the line between x1 y2 and x2 y2, with x2 y2 being the other dot that defines the tangent.

Comment: There are no "tangents" here, just orthogonal lines.

Comment: There's no magic here. A vertical line has infinite slope. If you want a different behavior in the case of a vertical line, then wrap your code in a condition checking for y1=y2 and do what you want to do in that case.

Comment: Agree, the best solution here is ruling out the situation the division by zero occurs, using an if clause, if it is a recurrent situation, or using try ... except case it is something that rarely happens.
Also by the equation presented, you can rewrite it as (y2-y1)/(x2-x1), so you need to test if x2 == x1 in the if clause.

Comment: @Metropolis: to obtain a second point (rather than a slope), there are no special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
X3 = X2 + (Y2 - Y1)
Y3 = X2 - (X2 - X1)
```